# Which route should be used?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql, routes, ruby-on-rails-4

I am trying to figure out what route I need to create to get something like the below to work. Thanks in advance!

Dashboard HTML:

```
%td= button_to "Join", { action: "join_group", id: group.id }, method: :post
```

Dashboard Controller:

```
def join_group
  group = Group.find(params[:id])
  user = current_user
  user.update(group_id: group)
end
```

Routes:

```
get '/dashboard', to: 'dashboard#index'
post '/dashboard', to: 'dashboard#index'
```

Comment: Yes the user has an attribute group_id. (also probably not the best way to do groups, but hey)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll need to add a route which matches your controller action, something along the lines of:

```
post 'join_group' => 'dashboard#join_group', as: 'join_group'
```

Note: The 'as' piece of this is not necessary here, but is handy if you want to rename the route helper that rails gives you.